# Error al ejecutar de nodejs y babel

Tags: nodejs, express, babel

Hola estoy aprendiendo node y estoy intentando configurar el servidor para crear una app para usar la api de paypal:

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();
app.listen(3000)
console.log("Server on port", 3000);
```

Al ejecutar el servidor:

```
PS C:\Users\home\Documents\nodejs-paypal> npm run dev nodejs-paypal@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\home\Documents\nodejs-paypal nodemon src/index.js --exec babel-node
```

Me genera el error:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.15
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `babel-node src/index.js`
C:\Users\home\Documents\nodejs-paypal\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:135
    throw unknownOptErr;
    ^

Error: Unknown option: .preset. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.
at throwUnknownError (C:\Users\home\Documents\nodejs-paypal\node_modules\←[4m@babel←[24m\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:133:27)
at C:\Users\home\Documents\nodejs-paypal\node_modules\←[4m@babel←[24m\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:118:5
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at validateNested (C:\Users\home\Documents\nodejs-paypal\node_modules\←[4m@babel←[24m\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:94:21)
at validate (C:\Users\home\Documents\nodejs-paypal\node_modules\←[4m@babel←[24m\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:85:10)
at C:\Users\home\Documents\nodejs-paypal\node_modules\←[4m@babel←[24m\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:209:34
at cachedFunction (C:\Users\home\Documents\nodejs-paypal\node_modules\←[4m@babel←[24m\core\lib\config\caching.js:60:27)
at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>) {
code: ←[32m'BABEL_UNKNOWN_OPTION'←[39m
}`
**[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...**
```

Answer (score 0):

El error estaba en la versión que tenia instalada de **nodejs**, ya que estaba utilizando un equipo con *windows 7*.

**Inicialicé el proyecto, instalé las dependencias nuevamente y pude ejecutar los servicios.**